# How to color groups of bars in a graph, coming form an external file?

Tags: pgfplots, color, external-files, graphs

I have a graph displaying bars and error bars, the numbers comming from an external .dat, being simply black and white.
[image: black and white graph]

And this is how I got there:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{figure} [ht]
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[xtick pos=left, unbounded coords=jump, scale=1.97, ybar, bar width=8pt, ylabel=$F_{Bruch}$\,${[N]}$,xtick=data,xticklabels from table={data.dat}{amount}]
    \addplot [error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit]
    table[x expr=\coordindex,y=FB,y error =sFB]{dataEB.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{-25pt}
\small
\begin{tabbing}
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx\=xxxx\kill
    \>\begin{tabular}[htbp]{*{6}{@{}c}}
    $\underbrace{\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;}$ & \;\;\;\;\,$\underbrace{\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;}$ & \;\;\,$\underbrace{\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;}$ & \,$\underbrace{\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;}$ & \,$\underbrace{\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;}$ & \;$\underbrace{\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;}$ \\
    PEL80\,L & \;\;\;\;PEL80\,B & \,\;\;\;\;PEL90A\,L & \;\;\;PEL90A\,B & \;\;\,PEL90B\,L & \;\;PEL90B\,B \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{tabbing}
\caption{bla bla}
\end{figure}
```

I had to tweak the original data, so the error bars are in correct position (had to insert a few nan to get my spacing).

And here is my question: How to get the bars of the different groups in different colors(e.g. PEL80L=red, PEL80B=green, ...)?
And is there a smarter way to put those brackets below the groups?

data.dat (shortened in rows and columns):

```
Name        FB  sFM seM sFB seB amount
PEL80-L-0   196.971 7.1561  20.3208 6.9981  18.3839 0
PEL80-L-5   187.389 7.5195  15.8812 8.0784  15.2679 5
PEL80-L-10  202.529 5.0238  7.0358  3.6911  7.8109  10
PEL80-L-15  194.160 16.3605 40.9362 12.9954 41.6095 15
PEL80-B-0   192.586 2.1435  6.5643  3.1437  7.9701  0
PEL80-B-5   130.047 36.6504 19.4086 36.3431 19.6311 5
PEL80-B-10  77.6493 8.6906  1.6346  8.6906  1.6346  10
PEL80-B-15  79.3942 6.1144  0.9555  5.3075  1.2452  15
```

dataEB.dat:

```
Name        FB  sFM seM sFB seB amount
PEL80-L-0   196.9710 7.1561 20.3208 6.9981  18.3839 0
PEL80-L-5   187.3894 7.5195 15.8812 8.0784  15.2679 5
PEL80-L-10  202.5292 5.0238 7.0358  3.6911  7.8109  10
PEL80-L-15  194.1602 16.360 40.9362 12.9954 41.6095 15
nan     nan  nan    nan nan nan 0
PEL80-B-0   192.5864 2.1435 6.5643  3.1437  7.9701  5
PEL80-B-5   130.0471 36.650 19.4086 36.3431 19.6311 10
PEL80-B-10  77.6493  8.6906 1.6346  8.6906  1.6346  15
PEL80-B-15  79.3942  6.1144 0.9555  5.3075  1.2452  0
nan     nan  nan    nan nan nan 5
```

Comment: Hi Beli, welcome to the site! Do you want to colour the bars by *series* (so one colour for each `\addplot` command) or by *group* (so one colour for PEL80 L, one colour for PEL80 B, and so on)? It would be good if you could make the code snippet a complete compilable document by including the data (or dummy data).

Comment: Can you provide a sample file of your data? Also, consider to make the width of your bars bigger, 10 and 15 are too close. »Bruch« is a textword, no variable, use `\text{Bruch}`. Units are typeset upright, use [siunitx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) nicer units. Also, according to DIN 461 you must not give the units in square brackets `[ ]`. You also may want to have a look at http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/2283/wie-erstelle-ich-mit-pgfplots-eine-pseudo-2d-darstellung

Comment: The width of the bars was chosen this tight so the whole graph fits my textwidht (it's already too large about 11 pt)

Comment: One suggestion: Put it in landscape.

Comment: There will be some text below the graph, so I would like to avoid rotating it.